# How do i make my Intel GPU (9a78 rev 01) compatible

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics

How do I make my GPU compatible safely without getting it to freeze on boot with workarounds?

```
(base) wal@len:~$ lspci | grep VGA
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a78 (rev 01)
(base) wal@len:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for wal: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:158 memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
(base) wal@len:~$ lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a78] (rev 01)
(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20210115-1).
xserver-xorg-video-intel set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

edit(@matigo): I did upgrade my OS from 20 to 22 in the past, but looks like the kernel thing didn't apply?

```
(base) wal@len:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-56-generic

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt -f install
[sudo] password for wal: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo aptitude -f install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:22.04.10).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

(base) wal@len:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: According to the Linux Kernel Driver Database, you need to be using [a Linux distribution with a kernel version of 5.4 or above](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DRM_I915.html). That said, a quick search online shows that you're better off with a kernel in the 6.x range. As there is no information about what OS you're running, I'll assume you're using a 5.x-series kernel. If you're semi-adventurous, [there is a quirks patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/early-quirks.c) that may help ... but this is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @matigo Hi thanks for your reply. You are right, seems like this machine uses `5.15.0-56-generic`(Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). Any idea how i upgrade it? I tried `apt -f` and `aptitude -f install` (updated original post)

Comment: @matigo I have some more general questions about Ubuntu. Usually the OS GUI updater notifies me for new package updates. every now and then I run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt dist-upgrade` for general updates for my Ubuntu machine if the updater misses something. 
 
How do you get informed for new kernel versions? It seems like kernel updates are considered a separate thing. 
Are there any other stuff I can make sure to check if they are updated? 

I want to add it to my terminal command for checking for updates (the one mentioned above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Intel GPU is fully supported. There is nothing to worry about.

It is using the `i915` driver. If everything works OK, then I see no problem.