# How do you keep your Ubuntu Desktop machine updated with the last stable upgrades? (OS version, kernel, packages)

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, versions

Following my previous post: [How do i make my Intel GPU (9a78 rev 01) compatible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448984/how-do-i-make-my-intel-gpu-9a78-rev-01-compatible)

I decided to create a different post since it got a different plot twist.
It started with my machine not knowing about my GPU and I got to understand that my kernel isn't updated.
The thing is - I upgraded my machine in the past from 20.04 to 22.04, and I want to believe that the kernel get's update too (?), but seems like the kernel didn't upgrade? or got downgraded?

```
(base) wal@len:~$ lspci | grep VGA
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a78 (rev 01)

(base) wal@len:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-56-generic

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt -f install
[sudo] password for wal: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo aptitude -f install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:22.04.10).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(base) wal@len:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

(base) wal@len:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

trying to follow: https://itslinuxfoss.com/check-update-ubuntu-kernel-version-ubuntu-22-04/
There's a list of kernels which I don't know which is the most recent stable: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

What are the best practices or your routines to automatically check for STABLE updates and upgrades (OS, kernel, packages, other[?])
I usually use:

`sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt dist-upgrade`

but apparently this isn't enough, and i want to add to it some more.
Are there any more automated safe ways to do that?
Please help me understand the concept of all of this?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy-updates&keywords=linux-generic says 5.15.0.57 is the latest for 22.04 and you're on 5.15.0.56, so it's not like you're months out-of-date or something. Did you run `sudo apt update` before trying to upgrade?

Comment: @muru sure, yes, i always run update before upgrade. It seems like 22.04 really includes the 5.15 kernel, and 20.04 has the 5.4 kernel. that's what mainly got me confused. the thing is that my gpu mightnot get get recognised because of the current kernel version, see link of my prev post at the top.

Comment: Even the still-in-development [23.04 has only kernel 5.19](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lunar&keywords=linux-generic), so if you want to install the mainline kernels you have linked to, see https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/158442

Comment: @RishonJR Not really the same. The same major version `5.15`, but not exactly same. And there is no 22.04.5 yet ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry that was a typo...What i meant was... 
20.04 LTS Provides almost the same kernel version as 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I periodically check kernels with the 'sudo apt install linux-image' command that outputs the list of kernels available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way of keeping your system up-to-date is to install upgrades suggested by the system. If you want to do it using CLI

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

is sufficient.

You are wrong saying that kernel is not upgrading. It does upgrade. `5.15.0-56-generic` is the current kernel for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so i know now that what i am doing is sufficient and that it's not a kernel thing.

Comment: Actually kernel `linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic` was just released, but maybe it hasn't been synced to local mirrors yet..

Comment: @ArturMeinild It did. I got it upgraded a few minutes age, but it doesn't make any difference. The upgrade will come depending on a used mirror sooner or later.